# Curl request not working to use hasoffers api

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl request to hit the has-offers conversion url from my sevrver with the help of curl but it is not working.But when I call the same URL using a browser, it works.Is they can block CURL requests?.I am not getting why, is there any port blocking issue.

Below is php code to call url using curl request.

```
<?php
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}

$url="http://paravey.go2cloud.org/aff_l?offer_id=12&aff_id=1000";
$contents = curl_get_contents($url);
echo $contents;
?>
```

Please help me thanks in Advance

Comment: The server is responding with an empty site under this url (even when visited with the browser):

https://pastebin.com/i62ac8tS

Comment: But this url working when i hit this on browser so its a port issue or something else.

Comment: This cant be a port issue, because you are requesting the same on the same port with curl and the browser (80)

Comment: i got this reponse from browser conversion logged: true

Comment: Are you logged in on this site, or do you have any cookie/session stored from the browser?

Comment: yes i have logged in so many times.so from your point of you view whats the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139327/discussion-between-varun-joshi-and-dzdomi).

Comment: When you are using the browser (and are logged in) you have a cookie stored in your browser which is sent to the server on each request. you also need to add this cookie to your curl request

Answer (score 0):

The url you are curling is a pixel tracking url:
http://paravey.go2cloud.org/aff_l?offer_id=12&aff_id=1000

The aff_l endpoint looks for a cookie with session information (hence why it works in the browser).

If you want to create conversions with server side code, you will need to store the session identifier (the transaction_id) in your system and use the aff_lsr endpoint to send that data to HasOffers to trigger a conversion.

The url for this would look like this:
http://paravey.go2cloud.org/aff_lsr?transaction_id= VALUE
Where Value is the session identifier you have stored.

I would ask the HasOffers support team if you have more issues with this.